# Передача данных с onBindViewHolder в другой фрагмент

Tags: java, android, recyclerview.adapter, android-bottomsheetbehavior

Есть активити (MainActivity) в нем подключен фрагмент (состоит с recyclerView в который рендерится список товаров), так же у фрагмент подключен bottomsheetbehavior в котором создан фильтр чекбоксов и в адаптере, в методе onBindViewHolder установлен листенер чекбокса при котором в массив заносится значение нажат чекбокс или нет, нажатие чекбоксов нужно связать с отображением данных recyclerView товаров. Вопрос, как передать данные с адаптера, что генерирует фильтр и перерисовать каталог товаров. Методы я все создал - подскажите пожалуйста как правильно их использовать.

```
public class CavaFragment extends AbstractTabFragment {
private static final int LAYOUT_FRAGMENT = R.layout.fragment_cava;
RecyclerView recyclerViewTovars;
List<ItemTovar> listTovars;
List<String> filtList;
private static BottomFragmentSetting bottomFragmentSetting;

public static CavaFragment getInstance(Context ctx){

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    CavaFragment cavaFragment = new CavaFragment();
    cavaFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    cavaFragment.setContext(ctx);
    cavaFragment.setTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.navigation_item_cava));
    return cavaFragment;
}
public static void showBottomBehavior(){
    bottomFragmentSetting.show();

}
public void setContext(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_FRAGMENT, container, false);

    recyclerViewTovars = view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

    recyclerViewTovars.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, 
LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

    ConnecterDTO connecterDTO = new ConnecterDTO();
    connecterDTO.execute();

    listTovars = null;
    try {
        listTovars = connecterDTO.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    TovarListAdapter tovarListAdapter = new TovarListAdapter(
            context,
            listTovars
    );

    recyclerViewTovars.setAdapter(tovarListAdapter);

    filtList = new ArrayList<>();
    filtList.addAll(FiltrListTov.getFiltrList());
    Collections.sort(filtList);

    bottomFragmentSetting = new BottomFragmentSetting(view, getContext(), 
 filtList);

    return view;
 }
 public void filtration(boolean[] show) {
    for(int  i = 0; i < show.length; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < listTovars.size(); i++){
            if(!show[i]){

  if(listTovars.get(j).getBrand_name().equals(filtList.get(i))){
                    listTovars.get(j).showable = false;
                }
            }
            if(i == 0 && !show[i]){
                if(listTovars.get(j).getType_weight() == 1){
                    listTovars.get(j).showable = false;
                }
            }
            if(i == 1 && !show[i]){
                if(listTovars.get(j).getType_weight() == 2){
                    listTovars.get(j).showable = false;
                }
            }
            if(i == 2 && !show[i]){
                if(listTovars.get(j).getType_weight() == 3){
                    listTovars.get(j).showable = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }

  }
 }
```

Код адаптера фильтра

```
public class FiltrListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<FiltrListAdapter.ViewHolder>{
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
List<String> listFiltrItems;

public static boolean[] show;

public FiltrListAdapter(Context context, List<String> list){
    this.context = context;
    listFiltrItems = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    show = new boolean[listFiltrItems.size()];

}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_filtr_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, 
@SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    holder.checkBox.setText(listFiltrItems.get(position));
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    show[position] = holder.checkBox.isChecked();
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean 
isChecked) {
            show[position] = isChecked;

            /*
            for (int i = 0; i < show.length; i++){
                if(show[i]){ Log.println(Log.INFO, "cheked_list", i + " - 
true"); }
                else{ Log.println(Log.INFO, "cheked_list", i + " - false"); 
}
                }
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "cheked_list", " - end ________________");
            */
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listFiltrItems.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkBox;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cbxFiltrItem);
    }
}

}
```

Нужно передать массив show в cavaFragment, затем вызвать метод filtration и перерисовать товары. Пробовал сделать это в адаптере фильтрации передавая туда ссылку на recycler и создавая новый адаптер - но приложение зависало.
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, если нужно больше кода - вот проект на гитхабе - [проект](https://github.com/Divinkas/tst.git)

Comment: Делайте через `interface`

Comment: Вам нужно обновлять список после каждого нажатия на элемент фильтра? Или у вас может быть кнопка, которая будет применять изменения внесенные в фильтр?

Comment: Обновлять после каждого нажатия на элемент